# Mvc .net Password change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am new with C# and MVC aplications.
I have weird issue with password change in MVC aplication.

The thing is next, when i fill my form and enter old and new password and hit enter, everything seams to went fine but the password is not updated in databse. Then when I do from second try it went fine.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bool changePasswordSucceeded;

        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
        changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);

        if (changePasswordSucceeded)
        {
            var user = GetUser();
             user.PasswordEntropyScore = model.PasswordEntropyScore;

            var userRepo = new UserRepository(MvcApplication.DbSession);
            userRepo.Update(user);

            return this.RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
        }
    }

    return this.View(model);
}
```

UserRepository Update() method is here:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>
{
    private Logger logger;

    public UserRepository(ISession sesh) : base(sesh)
    {
        this.logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public new bool Update(User user)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.UserName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email))
        {
            var ex = new ArgumentException("Username or Email cannot be blank");
            this.logger.Error("User.Update - username or email was null/empty string.", LoggerHelper.GetErrorString(ex, user));
            throw ex;
        }

        return base.Update(user);
    }      
}
```

And repository base.Update() method:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    protected readonly ISession session;
    protected static Logger logger;

    public Repository()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Must instantiate repositories with an ISession");
    }

    public Repository(ISession sesh)
    {
        this.session = sesh;
        logger = new LogFactory().GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public bool Update(T entity)
    {
        this.session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
        this.session.Flush();
        return true;
    }
}
```

So all this code went fine when first time I tried to change password but it doens't udapted it in database. Then when I try the second time to change the password then it update in database.

If I change the code to directly call base.Update() method instead to call first UserRepostirory.Update() method as wrapper then it is fine.

Does anyone has idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

there is not much comment in your code to understand what you really did but if you use entity framework you can simply do like below:

```
entitymodel model= new entitymodel();
var query= model.users.first(o=>userID==inputID);
query.password=inputPassword;
model.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the code I do not see any issues. Is it possible to add try catch block to Repository class Update Method and check if any exception is occurred when you are trying to save for the first time.

Can you check if MvcApplication.DBSession is set before hitting Update method for the first time

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of having entity framework local cache which may be updating password to older one. Perform below steps.

1. Remove below lines from your code.
2. Change password
3. Restart application and check if password is changed or not.

If password is changed then clear entity framework local cache(by code).

NOTE: There is no need of updating password in db again. ChangePassword function makes changes to DB directly.

[image]